# Какое сообщение будет выдавать API.Яндекс карт (расширенная лицензия) при превышении лимита запросов в сутки?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Планируем использовать API.Яндекс карт  (расширенная лицензия). 
У них есть ограничение -  до 1000 запросов в сутки
Какое сообщение будет выдавать API при превышении лимита запросов в сутки?

Comment: А почему бы не спросить у них самих

Comment: Сюда отсылают :)

Comment: Это же не технический вопрос, а скорее вопрос про спецификацию сервиса - его лучше задавать техподдержке. Но вообще должна быть ошибка 403.